# How to completely delete my USB thumbstick?

Tags: windows, usb, partitioning

I own a Kingston thumb-stick. I have installed a Google Chrome OS image to it, so I could try it out. When it did so, it created 3 partitions (I backed everything up and the software that installed Chrome OS deleted my thumb-stick completely and created three partitions).

Now I want to get it back to one partition, but when I go to Disk Management, it will not let me "extend" the partition. I have tried different partitioning tools but they didn't recognize my thumb-stick anyway. I have also tried [diskpart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diskpart) to no avail. Is there any software that will completely format my thumb-stick so I would only have one partition?

Comment: Seriously? A [**thumb-stick**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog_stick)?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **[Active@KillDisk](http://www.killdisk.com/)**; the free version includes a Windows application that will do the job.

[image]

Comment: Thank YOU so much!!! I can't believe I didn't know that. Well I'm learning something new everyday :D

Comment: umm, i suppose you have found that out by now :) and you're more than welcome.

Comment: lol, yeah I figured it out :P

Answer (score 2):

Active KillDisk will not see the linux formatted partitions and will not erase the entire disk when using it within windows. It will work on Linux though. Use dariks boot and nuke instead http://dban.org.

Comment: I beg to differ: Killdisk will KILL all partitions regardless the filesystem, only  the 'Wipe Free Space' feature doesn't work on linux filesystems when using it in Windows.

Comment: No It won't see the volume's full size if it has linux partitions.

Comment: yes, it does, i just 'killed' a USB stick formatted with Ext3 with KillDisk in Windows, no problem.

Comment: + 1 anyway, i won't argue anymore about it because DBAN is overall the better software. the reason i recommended Killdisk: the Windows version kills USB drives just fine whereas DBAN sometimes has trouble detecting USB devices ... and in this case even the best software in the world is quite useless for the task at hand. :)

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: Write the .img into USB

### DELETING THE IMAGE

1. Use `DISKPART` to clean the drive
2. open / run `DISKMGMT.MSC` to create partition primary, any Filesystem would be fine for now
3. use windows right-click `FORMAT` then choose new preferred Filesystem

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with the Computer management tool in Windows. right-click 'My Computer' then choose 'manage'. In there you find 'disk management', it lists all your disks and you will see that your USB key has more than one partition, delete all partitions and format the key from there.

Answer (score 0):

Use this: [HP USB Disk Storage Format Tool](http://www.softpedia.com/progDownload/HP-USB-Disk-Storage-Format-Tool-Download-123786.html)

> HP USB Disk Storage Format Tool was developed to be a Windows-based
>   format utility for the HP Drive Key or DiskOnKey USB 2.0 device.Users
>   have the possibility to easily create bootable disks, or change the
>   file system from FAT to NTFS for their Flash drives.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit on how one would use it?